# removing blank lines from a file

Tags: java

i am trying to remove blank lines fom a file by adding following coedes to my program

```
private static void Normalize(File f) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

                    if(!temp.exists()){
                         temp.createNewFile();
                    }

                    FileOutputStream fop=new FileOutputStream(temp,true);

                    Set<String> uniqueLines = new HashSet<String>();
                    BufferedReader  br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
                    String readLine=br.readLine();
                    for(final String s : readLine.split(" ")){
                        fop.write(s.getBytes());
                        fop.write(System.getProperty("line.separator").getBytes());

                    }
                    uniqueLines.add(readLine);
                    while((readLine=br.readLine())!=null)
                    {

                       if (!uniqueLines.contains(readLine)) {

                         for(final String s : readLine.split(" ")){
                            fop.write(s.getBytes());
                            fop.write(System.getProperty("line.separator").getBytes());

                        }

                        uniqueLines.add(readLine);
                    }
                  }
                }
```

but the problem is, there still remains some of the blank lines which makes problem for the rest of my program. any idea how to fix it?

EDIT

Maybe this would help. the reason I want to delete blank lines is when I use Tokenizer, it will give an exception when it reaches the blank lines:

```
   String finished=tokenizer.nextToken();
    if(!stopWords.contains(finished))
    {
    write(finished); 

    }
```

at Write part it gives the `NotsuchElementExist` Exception

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
 while((readLine=br.readLine())!=null)
  {

   if (readLine.isEmpty() || readLine.trim().equals("") || readLine.trim().equals("\n"))
        continue;
...
```

Comment: blank line doesnt mean it is empty. it will fail surely.

Comment: If it is not blank then it is Not empty. I think This will work on Blank lines I think it is a definition of blank.

Comment: it will remove some of blanks but still one or two remains plus, after this function ends, it will stop to continue tp rest of my program, when i add isEmpty part and when i remove it, it goes to excuting the rest of program but then stops by an exception causing by blank lines